# How to close or end an app without the operating system telling me that the event has happened?

Tags: android, kill, restart

I have tried the following ways to finalize an application that is made in android studio:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(1);
System.exit(0);
```

All works, but the operating system shows me a message saying that the application has stopped and there is a button that says "restart application"

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Simple: do not attempt to "finalize an application". Android will terminate your process on its own when it needs the system RAM to support other apps. As a bonus, if the user returns to your app quickly, your process is still around, and so you do not need to reload data from disk or the network.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried ?

`this.finishAffinity();`

or

```
finishAndRemoveTask ();
```

Use `System.exit(0);` is a bad solution to finish an App.

Comment: this.finishAffinity() works fine but with jelly bean or a superior version

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    this.finishAffinity();
                }